# input() inside a function throws an exception->"input() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given"

Tags: python

```
def input():
    number = int(input('enter a number: '))
    return number

input()

def checkValidity(val):
    if val == 0 and val >= 2:
        switch(val)
    else:
        input()

def switch(num):
    if num == 1:
        print('one')
    elif num == 2:
        print('two')
    else:
        print('null')

checkValidity(number)
```

the `input()` works fine when defined without a function, but when defined in a function and called, it throws an exception.

Comment: Rename your input function to something else and it'll work, don't shadow inbuilts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should not name your function `input()` since it is an internal function already! your function should be called `my_user_input()` or something similar.

By calling your own function `input()`, you shadow and therefore "overwrite" the existing, BuiltIn-`input()`-function. This way, you won't be able to access it's functionality any more inside the script.

Comment: I agree that the function name is the source of the problem, but I feel it should be clarified that "you cannot name your function input()" means "you can't do this and expect to be able to access the built-in function by that same name" rather than "you are not allowed to do this, full stop". Overshadowing built-in function names is legal, it's just not a good idea the vast majority of the time.

Comment: will incorporate it in my answer! I guess that by defining `input()` on my own, I overwrite the buildin input-function?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "overwrite". If you define your own `input()`, then the original `input()` function still exists in memory. It's just not accessible by that name any more. It's still recoverable (e.g. by reassigning it later with `input = __builtins__.input`, or simply leaving the scope where the assignment occurred), but it's easier to just not use that name to begin with.

Comment: ok, got it! never thought about this concept before, but then I guess I clarified it corectly in the edited answer. thanks a lot!

Comment: but i still get an error, NameError("name 'number' is not defined",)
Stack trace:
 >  File "f:\projects\pythonapplication\pythonapplication1\pythonapplication1.py", line 21, in <module>
 >    checkValidity(number)
Loaded '__main__'
The program 'python.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff), the number variable in the input function cannot be accessed by the checkValidity().

Comment: because you have two different variables which you call "number" - try to name all your variables in a distinct way